# Play/Pause video when listitem get visible in recyclerview

Tags: android-scrollview, android-recyclerview, android-textureview, onscrollchanged

I have implemented a recyclerview in which i am adding textures views as list items to play videos from url. Now like vine and instagram app i want to play a video when it is visible in the recyclerview and stop/pause video when listitem gets out of screen. Following is my code:

VideosAdapter Class:

```
public class VideosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideosAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static String TAG = "VideosAdapter";

Context context;
private ArrayList<String> urls;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextureView textureView;
    public TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        textureView = (TextureView) v.findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    }
}

public VideosAdapter(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, final ArrayList<String> urls) {

    this.context = context;
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    this.urls = urls;

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
                int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                int findLastVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                *//*Log.i(TAG, "firstVisiblePosition = " + String.valueOf(firstVisiblePosition));
                Log.i(TAG, "findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = " + String.valueOf(findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition));
                Log.i(TAG, "findLastVisibleItemPosition = " + String.valueOf(findLastVisibleItemPosition));
                Log.i(TAG, "findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = " + String.valueOf(findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition));*//*

                Log.i(TAG, "//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");

                if(findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition>=0) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Playing_URl = " + urls.get(findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition));
                    int tempPreviousUrl = findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition - 1;
                    if(tempPreviousUrl>=0)
                        Log.i(TAG, "Stop_Playing_URl = " + urls.get(tempPreviousUrl));

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Playing_URl = " + urls.get(firstVisiblePosition));
                    int tempPreviousUrl = firstVisiblePosition - 1;
                    if(tempPreviousUrl>=0)
                        Log.i(TAG, "Stop_Playing_URl = " + urls.get(tempPreviousUrl));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public VideosAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_main, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String url = urls.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(url);

    //Log.i("BindViewHolderCalledFor", position + " = " + url);

    VideoPlayController videoPlayController = new VideoPlayController(context, recyclerView, holder.textureView, url);

    if(position==0) {
        videoPlayController.loadVideo();
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return urls.size();
}
```

}

VideoPlayController Class:

```
public class VideoPlayController implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

private static String TAG = "VideoPlayController";

Context context;
String url;
MediaPlayer mp;
Surface surface;
SurfaceTexture s;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
TextureView textureView;

public VideoPlayController(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, TextureView textureView, final String url) {

    this.context = context;
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    this.textureView = textureView;
    this.url = url;

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                Log.i(TAG, "OnScrollStateChangedCalled For: " + url);

                //When scroll is at idol position check if item is visible

            }
        }
    });

}

public void loadVideo() {

    textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(final SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    Log.d("surface_available-url", this.url);
    startVideo(surface);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    Log.d("surface_destroyed-url", this.url);
}

@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    Log.d("surface_destroyed-url", this.url);
    this.mp.stop();
    this.mp.reset();
    this.mp.release();
    this.mp = null;
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

}

public void startVideo(SurfaceTexture t)
{
    this.surface = new Surface(t);
    this.mp = new MediaPlayer();
    this.mp.setSurface(this.surface);
    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(this.url);
        this.mp.setDataSource(url);
        this.mp.prepareAsync();

        this.mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start();

            }
        });
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void changePlayState()
{
    if(this.mp.isPlaying())
        this.mp.stop();
    else
        this.mp.start();
}

public static boolean isViewVisible(View subView, View parentView) {
    Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
    parentView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
    if (subView.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

To achieve this thing i get visible items positions as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview) thread. But i dont know how to pass the visible scroll position to my VideoPlayController class and how to track and access the right object based on scroll position.

Comment: How did you achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but many people are still looking for a way to do this.
You can use [VideoPlayerManager](https://github.com/danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager) project, to achieve this functionality