# Android - RecyclerView to have first row (and values of row) always when I scrolling

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I need to have first row(and values of row) always when I scrolling.
I have a `RecyclerView`I need that when I scrolling my `recycle` and when arrive `Row eight` to position of `Row one` I visible a `TextView` for shown a something, for example a Title. How I can mange it?

[image]

For example when yellow row arrive to position of row green I visible a `TextView`.

[image]

I don't know how I can get `position` first row of `Layout` from `Activity`.

NOTICE : I don't need to use libraries of `GitHub`. Thanks

Comment: I donot understand what you alredy have and what are you missing. the translation between position and viewitem is done in the adapter.

Comment: My english is poor . sorry

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview you may want to look at this.

Comment: @Angel Koh .Thanks,but get me -1 always .

Answer (score 1):

first / last visible child depends on the LayoutManager. If you are using LinearLayoutManager or GridLayoutManager, you can use

```
int findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

For example:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = ((GridLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```

Comment: How I can use from them ? Get me a link for sample . Thanks

Comment: Thanks,but get me -1 always .