# RecyclerView: Set scroll position so that item appears at the bottom of the view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I have a `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager` that is backed by an adapter with items **of different height**. Is there a way to tell the `RecyclerView` to set the scroll position so that item X appears (more or less) exactly at the bottom of the screen?

I tried `LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition()` but this will position the item at the top of the view.

Comment: DIdn't scrollToPosition() work? Not sure about the bottom of the screen.

Comment: `scrollToPosition()` will position the item at the top of the view. I want the opposite.

Comment: Hop you could attach the info on this link to it and work around for a way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 2):

```
MyAdapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<ItemData> data = new ArrayList<>();
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
```

try this in OnCreate method

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
llm.setStackFromEnd(true);
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(data, getApplication());
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

and when you insert an item try this

```
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(data.size() - 1);
llm.scrollToPosition(data.size() - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in mainActivity.class

```
 rv_journey.setAdapter(ca);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scrollList();
                }
            }, 500);
```

Here is my scroll Method

```
private void scrollList(){
        rv_journey.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Call smooth scroll
                rv_journey.smoothScrollToPosition(Index);
            }
        });
    }
```

Set index from Adapter class which extend RecyclerView.Adapter Where You need to scroll...

```
if (Condition) {
                        mainActivity.Index=position+1;

                    }
                }
```

Happy Coding...