# Android how can I get current positon on recyclerview that user scrolled to item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my `RecyclerView` I have some items that user can scroll and see that. Now I want to save this position and scroll that after come back. This below code return 0 always and I can't save that:

```
recyclerMarketLists.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        recyclerViewCurrentScrolledPosition = recyclerMarketLists.getScrollY();
        Log.e("Y: ", recyclerViewCurrentSceolledPosition + "");
    }
});
```

**the Logcat:**

```
07-07 18:28:30.919 2124-2124/com.sample.presentationproject E/Y:: 0
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You are trying to get the info on the wrong object. It is not the `RecyclerView` nor the `Adapter` responsibility but the RecyclerView's LayoutManager.

Instead of the generic `ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener()` I would recommend to add instead the `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` and use the `onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)` callback which gives you the `newState`, you should use `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` to fetch its position. Meaning:

```
yourRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```

> As Rik van Velzen pointed out, you probably need to cast your
>   `LayoutManager`  to a `LinearLayoutManager` or `GridLayoutManager`
>   (you have to cast to the correct type you are using) to access these
>   `findVisibleXXXX()` methods.

On said callback method. Hope I made this clear enough for your, you can find documentation on the classes here:

[RecyclerView.OnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html)

[yigit's (Google) response on visible positions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25053500/3374428)

Comment: linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(intemIndex, pxFromTop);

If it was helpful please upvote my answer.

Comment: is this correct: `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(recyclerViewLastPosition);`

Comment: Yes. You can also use smoothScroll for visual candy

Comment: When I call the `scrollToPosition` it never ends scrolling. Any clues?

Comment: Depends, what position are you scrolling to? What layout, dataset etc.? Need more context :)

Comment: You might need to cast the LayoutManager to a Linear or GridLayoutManager etc. when calling getLayoutManager() to be able to call findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

Comment: Yes, you're right, I'll edit my answer to include your tip.

Comment: This is the correct answer.
Had to do something similar, I have added it as answer because it exceeded the character limit for comments.

Answer (score 34):

Thanks for solution **Joaquim Ley**. This helps create `recyclerView` `horizontal` pager without using any library.

Init `recyclerView`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vocabulary_list);

    // Set up the recyclerView with the sections adapter.
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new VocabularyListAdapter<>(vocabularyList));
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
                int position = getCurrentItem();
                onPageChanged(position);
            }
        }
    });
    PagerSnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
}



public boolean hasPreview() {
   return getCurrentItem() > 0;
}

public boolean hasNext() {
    return mRecyclerView.getAdapter() != null &&
            getCurrentItem() < (mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()- 1);
}

public void preview() {
    int position = getCurrentItem();
    if (position > 0)
        setCurrentItem(position -1, true);
}

public void next() {
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = mRecyclerView.getAdapter();
    if (adapter == null)
        return;

    int position = getCurrentItem();
    int count = adapter.getItemCount();
    if (position < (count -1))
        setCurrentItem(position + 1, true);
}

private int getCurrentItem(){
    return ((LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager())
            .findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
}

private void setCurrentItem(int position, boolean smooth){
    if (smooth)
        mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
    else
        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, please let me to check that :)

Comment: PagerSnapHelper control scroling for item to item like ViewPger

Comment: Glad I could help out, although it seems like you are creating objects every time your `RecyclerView` is touched, not sure this is the most performant.

Answer (score 18):

This is the extension function in Kotlin:

```
fun RecyclerView?.getCurrentPosition() : Int {
    return (this?.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
}
```

You can use it just invoking this function on your `RecyclerView`:

```
val position = yourRecyclerView.getCurrentPosition()
```

Comment: its not advisiable to direct cast via `as` and use `!!` . instead, nullable casting via `as?` followed by elvis (`?:0`) is much safer

Answer (score 5):

Try this in Kotlin:

```
myRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        val offset: Int = myRecyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollOffset()
        if (offset % myRecyclerView.width == 0) {
            val position: Int = offset / myRecyclerView.width
            Log.e("Current position is", position.toString())
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I made 7 changes in my MainActivity and got pixel-perfect results. My recyclerview ALWAYS remembers its previous state when returning to it from some other Activity (e.g. DetailActivity).

Step 1: Initialize the layoutManager like so:

```
    // Initialize the layout manager
    moviePosterLayoutManager = (moviePosterRecyclerView.getLayoutManager() == null) ?
    new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns) :  moviePosterRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            // create a new layoutManager                       // reuse the existing layoutManager
```

Step 2: 
Inside your MainActivity class, create a STATIC variable to hold your layout manager state as you transition between activities:

```
private static Parcelable layoutManagerState;
```

Step 3: 
Also create this constant inside of the MainActivity () as well:

public static final String KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER_STATE = "layoutManagerState";

Step 4:
Inside the onCreate method for your MainActivity perform the following test, (i.e.

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {....

    if (layoutManagerState != null) {
        //moviePosterLayoutManager
        moviePosterLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(layoutManagerState);
        moviePosterRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(moviePosterLayoutManager);

    } else {

        moviePosterRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(moviePosterLayoutManager);
        moviePosterRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(moviePosition);
                                 // the default position

    }
```

Step 5: 
In your onSaveInstanceState method, be sure to 
    save your layoutManagerState as a parcelable like so:

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

```
   layoutManagerState = moviePosterLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();

    // Save currently selected layout manager.            
   outState.putParcelable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER_STATE,layoutManagerState);
}
```

Step 6:
Place similar code in the onResume() method of MainActivity:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    if (layoutManagerState != null) {
        moviePosterLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(layoutManagerState);
    }

}
```

Step 7:
Remember that all of this code was placed inside of my MainActivity.java file  It is important 
to remember that the layoutManager is responsible for maintaining the scroll position of the
recycler view. So, saving the state of the layoutManager is of paramount importance. The code could
modularized and placed inside a custom recyclerview, but I found this to be simpler for me to 
implement.

Comment: This worked very well for me - pixel perfect was correct.

Comment: Where you get the moviePosition value from?

Answer (score 2):

For a similar requirement plus some action needed to be performed on scroll state changed, I did this with a custom scroll listener:

```
class OnScrollListener(private val action: () -> Unit) : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

private var actionExecuted: Boolean = false
private var oldScrollPosition: Int = 0

override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
    when (newState) {
        RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING -> actionExecuted = false
        RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING -> actionExecuted = false
        RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE -> {

            val scrolledPosition =
                (recyclerView.layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager)?.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() ?: return

            if (scrolledPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && scrolledPosition != oldScrollPosition && !actionExecuted) {
                action.invoke()
                actionExecuted = true
                oldScrollPosition = scrolledPosition
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

This is because of the pre-existing bug with RecyclerView onScroll which happens to trigger the callback 2-3 or even more times. And if there is some action to be performed, that will end up executing multiple times.

Comment: Can you explain where and how to use this class, plz? TNX.

Comment: @ReyhaneFarshbaf You can use this class where you use the recycler view e.g. in Fragment or Activity. 
You can create a new instance of the `ScrollListener` by passing an action lambda. Then attach it to the recycler view like: `recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener)`

Answer (score 1):

```
    learnRecycleView
        .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                   int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                int offset=learnRecycleView.computeHorizontalScrollOffset();

                if (offset % learnRecycleView.getWidth() == 0) {
                    int position = offset / learnRecycleView.getWidth();
                    System.out.println("Current position is"+position);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions worked, I have achieved this by using layout manager.
Here is the Extension function for recyclerview

```
fun RecyclerView.addScrollListener(onScroll: (position: Int) -> Unit) {
    var lastPosition = 0
    addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            if (layoutManager is LinearLayoutManager) {
                val currentVisibleItemPosition =
                    (layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

                if (lastPosition != currentVisibleItemPosition && currentVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    onScroll.invoke(currentVisibleItemPosition)
                    lastPosition = currentVisibleItemPosition
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

You can use it like this on recyclerview.

```
 campusFeedRv.addScrollListener { position: Int ->
            Log.d(TAG, "Current Position: $position ")
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I need my current position view in Activity so I create a call-back method and using the below method.

Add this code in the **Adapter** class to get the current position of view.

Add this in **onBindViewHolder** method.

```
holder.imgProductParts.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
                onPositionChangeListener.onItemChanged(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) { }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Extension Way**

> Will return the recycler view **current item position**
>
> Extension **Function** ==>

```
fun RecyclerView.onScrollDoneGetPosition(onScrollUpdate: (Int) -> Unit) {
    this.addOnScrollListener(object :
        RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        }

        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            when (newState) {
                AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING -> {
                }
                AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                    print("When User Done it's Scroll")
                    val currentPosition =
                        (this@onScrollDoneGetPosition.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                    onScrollUpdate.invoke(currentPosition)
                }
                AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL -> {
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

> ***Usage ==>***

```
yourRecyclerView.onScrollDoneGetPosition() { pos ->
 populateData(pos)
}
```

> **Additional ==>**
>
> recycler view only one item per swipe restriction

```
 val snap = PagerSnapHelper()
 snap.attachToRecyclerView(yourRecyclerView)
```

*## Happy codding ##*