# How to find the position of current visible item in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an app which slideshows the images using RecyclerView. I used the below code to horizontally scroll the recycler view.

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, false);
imageListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Also, I am using the below code to scroll one item at a time.

```
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(imageListRecyclerView);
```

The problem is that I want to get the position of current visible item using

```
holder.getAdapterPosition()
```

but it is not working. Can anyone tell how to do it?

Comment: Why don't you use `ViewPager`

Comment: I know that but I can't use ViewPager.

Comment: here's the kotlin way:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72570694/14190819

Answer (score 6):

There are some helper methods of `LinearLayoutManager`

```
findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
Returns the adapter position of the first fully visible view.

int findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
Returns the adapter position of the first visible view.

int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
Returns the adapter position of the last fully visible view.

findLastVisibleItemPosition()
```

for more information check [this official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()).

Comment: I am using these in onScrollListener() of Recyclerview, and it doesn't works.

Comment: What problem are you facing while using these? @TavinderSingh

Comment: @karandeepsingh
I'm using the same in onScrollListener and the reason it doesn't work is because as the user scrolls to let's say previous days, I prepend data to my datasource, and notifyItemInserted runs. Once it runs, `findFirstVisibleItemPosition` returns 0

Answer (score 2):

Following `Linear / Grid LayoutManager` methods can be used to check which items are `visible`

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());

int findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastVisibleItemPosition();
int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

and if you want to track `is item visible on screen` for some `threshold` means `user spent enough time to view the content` then you can refer to the following blog.

a very nice blog which demonstrates the use of `scroll callbacks of LayoutManager` and `RxJava Subscribers` to track item visibility meets the threshold
https://proandroiddev.com/detecting-list-items-perceived-by-user-8f164dfb1d05

Comment: these simply do not work in any meaningful way

Comment: What do you mean by `any meaningful way` if you have any scenario, where it is not working then you can add sample code link here.