# RadListView scrollPosition property for android

Tags: nativescript

I'm looking for a workaround for using `RadListView`'s `scrollPosition` property in Android, as it is available only in [iOS](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radlistview.html#scrollposition).
Trying to look for some properties in android's `RecyclerView` [widget docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView)
Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38248034

Since RadListView code is closed source, you'd probably have to inspect it to check what classes it's using underneath. As it [extends RecyclerView](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/android/AndroidControlsDoc/com/telerik/widget/list/RadListView.html), you could try `radlistview.android.getLayoutManager()`, find out which class it is and call the equivalent method to get the view id (each LayoutManager has it's own `findFirst...()` method).