# How to get completely visible item position in android listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Currently I'm using `RecyclerView` for displaying a list. In `RecyclerView`, I am able to find the last completely visible item position using `LayoutManager`.

So my question is: In `ListView` Is there any possible way to get completely visible item position?

```
 mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, Didn't get it. Elaborate it more or post the code snippet which you tried.

Comment: Currently I'm using recyclerview for displaying list. In recyclerview I can able to find the last completely visible item position using layout manager. So my question is, In list view Is there any possible way to get completely visible item position?  "mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();"

Comment: what do u mean "get completely visible item position" ??? Means you want position of all items in list? right?

Comment: No....i want "findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition" count  from listview like recycler view     mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

Comment: **Check this** - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview Hope it will help!

Comment: But i am using listview only not a RecyclerView... please help

Comment: You said **"I'm using RecyclerView for displaying list"**. Check your question. Btw listview and recyclerview is not different. RecyclerView is just improved version of ListView.

Comment: ok..... But is it possible to get a "findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition" from listview. i am using Listview only.. sorry for the question mistakes....please help... i am struck

Comment: Yes. Check the link above. The answer in link is also applicable to listview. Just try it.

Comment: i am new for this... so please explain how to do...

Comment: i having error in  "listview.getLayoutManager();"... And cant able to use LinearLayoutManger for listview...