# Android: Using RecyclerView How to find x offset and y offset?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

I need every scroll count(increasing the count variable) while scroll the recyclerview, without using position. Because before i am using postion to increasing the count but its made some duplicate count . 
I Using the Recycler View but I am unable to get the current scroll offset in X direction of the recyclerView?

Comment: not yet code. ...........

Comment: just i am asking how to do this. because i am new for this task.

Comment: see this accepted answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview