# Check whether recyclerview item row is on screen or not?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to check whether the recyclerview item row is currently visible on screen or not, not getting the exact solution.

(And Please I'm NOT Searching for:[This: Get visible items in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview) ).

In RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MainVH holder, final int position) {...
    ...
...
int firstvisItemPosition =  manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        if (holder.imgGridImage != null && (firstvisItemPosition == position)) {
            holder.imgGridImage.setTag(1);
        } else {
            holder.imgGridImage.setTag(0);
        }
.
.
.
AND
.
.
.
holder.imgGridImage.getTag()
```

is not working for me,
Can any one help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get visible items in RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview)

Comment: @Aksahy, Actually it is not the thing working for me, see I've already stated that in the question that i'm not watching for that. But, thanks for reply.

Comment: You can use the answer in the link you specified and check the position of itemview is in range of that visible range

Comment: I did that but, solution I need is not drawn by that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check last row is visible or not by applying following method.

```
layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == adapter.getItemCount() - 1
```

if it returns true then last raw is visible.