# How to get ALWAYS the first element of the recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to remove a specific item (FIRST ITEM!) from the recyclerview.

its not a problem:

```
//items variable is my Arraylist
items.remove(0);
```

Its working okay, when i see the item. But when I scroll, the recyclerview updates itself, and if I scroll then try to remove the item its not the first item (0). What is the code, to remove the first item in ANY case?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to update arraylist which you have used in your adapter, and also needs to refresh `RecyclerView`

Comment: can you explain it more, to how to do that?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data)

Comment: i dont have problem with deleting an item, the problem is its not the right item. when i scroll, the first item wont be the first item.. how to tell the adapter, that i need to remove the first item?

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<Item> mItems;
private MyAdapter mAdapter;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // ... On Bind
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    // View holder class to save view elements
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // ...
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // ...
        }
    }
}

private void removeFirstItem() {
    mItems.remove(0);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Or use `notifyItemRemoved(position)` to remove with animation.

Comment: this is not working. "Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling"

Comment: You need to remove first item in list or first item in screen?

Comment: from the list yes

Comment: Can you post your code in which you are getting "Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling" error?

Comment: this is your removeFirstItem method, but when i put in a try catch block its working, removing the item, BUT not the first item.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read the answers in this question [Get visible items in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview).

Besides you can not call `notifyItemRemoved` and other notify method before activity is created, or you will get an error "Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling"

Comment: how can i use the findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition(); methods in the adapter class?

Comment: save the layoutManager as a member of adapter, is it hard?