# Calculate RecyclerView item visibility percentage inside Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, adapter

I want to know the item visibility percentage inside recycler view adapter. Is there any event when item is attached to the recyclerView? Or how can I highlight the middle item (which is visible) in vertical recyclerView.

Actually I want to change the background colour of cardView if its visibility turns 100%.

Thanks

Comment: What RecyclerView? Which CardView? Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: Here is answer - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

You can find visible item from the command

```
int findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```