# get visible item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I get a current item in `RecycerView`? In my use-case RV item takes all screen space, so there is only one item at a time. 
I've tried to google before, but nothing helpful was found.

**The whole use case:**

1. UI. The bottom navigation has a button that should call a certain method (let's say a `foo()` method) in fragment
2. this `foo()` method should get a visible item from the adapter and call a specific method in a presenter.

Answer (score 4):

use this in your code

```
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

and get your visible item using below code

```
mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```

Comment: yeah, I can get a position, but how I can get an item? Even more, based on this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25053500/1752729), it is not the best approach

Answer (score 1):

You could also use an OnItemClickListener on your RecyclerView's ListAdapter to determine the current item. In that case the item needs to be clicked though.

Comment: it's not my use case(

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
val position = (recyclerView?.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
val product = adapter?.getItemByPosition(position)
FirebaseCrash.logcat(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "onNavClickEvent = $product")
product?.let { productListViewModel?.order(it.id) }
```

The result is:

```
onNavClickEvent = Product(id=1, title='Cap', description='some descr.', price=10, photo='http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1/')
```