# findViewByPosition() of recyclerview shows null after notifydatasetChanged()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, findviewbyid

I have `recyclerview` in that i need to color 1st item's `button`.

so that I use following way,after `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
View viewItem = rvProductList.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(0);
```

but `viewItem` is getting `null`.

Is there any way of getting first items position?

Comment: this is because first item is already recycled (not visible)

Comment: if you want to find the position of the first fully visible item, you can use
int firstCompleteleyVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

Check this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25053500/5392118)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the view at position 0 is recycled at certain position. If you want to test it clearly. Check null viewItem in two case:

1. Scroll your recycle view up to top, when you can see the 1st item. Then call this and check null

   ```
   View viewItem = rvProductList.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(0);
   ```
2. Scroll down till 1st item being invisible to you, take action like case 1 and check null again.

**UPDATE SOLUTION**:
Solution is set the flag to know when you want to color 1st item. And in `onBindViewHolder()` method do this

```
@Override public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // I suppose that flag is true then we color 1st item
    if(position == 0 && flag) {
        // color your button here
    } else {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Hope it help!

Comment: I wanted to do it from activity

Comment: sorry about late reply. you can control that logic by update flag value from your activity. set it's value is true/false and call notifyDataSetChanged