# RecyclerView - Any way to get how many items are visible on screen before user starts scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

One of my activities contain a RecyclerView. 
On launching the activity, I want to know how many times `onBindViewHolder()` would run before user does any scrolling. Using logging, I checked that it runs almost as many times as the number of items visible on the screen. So essentially I want to know how many items are visible on the screen.

`getItemCount()` gives the total number of items. This is not what I want.

Is there any other way or method to get only the count of visible items?

I checked this post, but it did not help my case - [Get visible items in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview)

Comment: "it did not help my case" -- what do you mean by this? `RecyclerView` does not know how many items are visible until they become visible, as the size of the items is not known ahead of time.

Comment: You can use a for loop in your `OnBindViewHolder()` and store the value in prefs... or give a ID for each item...

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't need to know ahead of time. I need to know only once they have become visible. Is there any way?

Comment: Then I do not understand why the question that you linked to "did not help in [your] case".

Answer (score 0):

To get RecyclerView visible count you can use `layoutManager.getChildCount()`.
But you have to use like this :

```
layoutManager.postOnAnimation(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Visible count " + layoutManager.getChildCount());
            }
        });
```