# Change the color of status bar in android, to whatever the color of list item is

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to make the color of the status bar the same as the item on the list view is being scrolled at that moment. Is there any way to do this? I would like to make it like the picture below. In this case, while continuing to scroll, the status bar would be orange, then red and so on. Thank you beforehand.

[image]

Comment: Would a transparent status bar do the job?

Comment: @0X0nosugar Yes it would work.

Comment: Then the code snippet  from the answer by @Nigel Brown should work nicely: create a color resource (in res/values/colors.xml) with value #00000000 and refer to this color resource. Use the code snippet e.g. in `onCreate()` of the `Activity` and voilà

Comment: @0X0nosugar Yes it worked now, thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this piece of code to programatically update the color of the status bar:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) }
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.actionbar_color));
}
```

You can look at this link on how to get the top visible item and then you can change the color based on that:
[Get visible items in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview)