# How to get recycler current visible item position

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

My recyclerview inside NestedScrollView view and recyclerview addOnScrollListener is not working but I need to get recyclerview current visible item position 

My experment

I use `"layoutmanager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()"` this code but it always showing last position only

 Is there any way to enable `addOnScrollListener` in recyclerview if it is inside NestedScrollView

This case is not similar to [Get visible items in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview) this question please read carefully

The solution provided in that post is working if it is not inside  NestedScrollView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get visible items in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview)

Comment: How is this different from the linked duplicate, and how did the answers not help?

Comment: You should not nest scrollable layouts, move the recyclerview inside a linear layout

Comment: we have another layout top of recyclerview in same page

Comment: @RobertDeNiro please check my answer.

Answer (score -2):

If I got you right, you would probably want to add a linear layout inside the scroll view, and in the linear layout add the recycler. There your addOnScrollListener supposed to work.

Another option here. You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083091/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-is-not-working) answer- there it's recommended to switch the scroll view with NestedScrollView .