# How to use scroll listener in onBindViewHolder in Adapter of a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a long itemView in `RecyclerView` adapter and what I want is a listener to check if a view in itemView is visible or not, while scrolling recyclerView.
What I need is somthing like "onRecyclerViewScrolled()" in this example code:

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder myViewHolder, int
            position) {

      onRecyclerViewScrolled() {
        if (!isVisible(myViewHolder.myView)) {
          //do something
        }
      }

    }

  }

  public static boolean isVisible(final View view) {
    if (view == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!view.isShown()) {
      return false;
    }
    final Rect actualPosition = new Rect();
    view.getGlobalVisibleRect(actualPosition);
    final Rect screen = new Rect(0, 0, getScreenWidth(), getScreenHeight());
    return actualPosition.intersect(screen);
  }

  public static int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
  }

  public static int getScreenHeight() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `addOnScrollListener` on your `RecyclerView` to get notified when the user scrolls, and you can get the first/last visible views from `LinearLayoutMangar` or `GridLayoutManager`:

```
        RecyclerView recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        reycler.setAdapter(YOUR_ADAPTER);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recycler.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                //First visible item position.
                int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                //Last visible item position.
                int lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();



               /*If you really need to access your visible views,
                 Loop through all the visible views*/.
                for (int position = firstVisiblePosition; position == lastVisiblePosition; position++) {
                    View lastVisibleView = layoutManager.getChildAt(firstVisiblePosition);
                    //do something
                }

                dataList.get(firstVisiblePosition);

            }
        });
```

More info from documentation `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` have to functions:

> onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
>     Callback method to be invoked when the RecyclerView has been scrolled.
>
> onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
>     Callback method to be invoked when RecyclerView's scroll state changes.

Apparently, `onScrolled` is called when the scroll is completed.

For more info see [Yigit answer`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25053500/6470661)