# How to get Visible positions from Recyclerview where it is inside the NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have Recyclerview inside the NestedScrollview.I need to get Visible positions from the RecyclerView but Recyclerview scroll listener is not triggered only Nestedscroll view scroll listener is triggered...

Comment: Probably because the `RecyclerView` expands to its maximum length. Is your `RecyclerView` orientaion `VERTICAL`?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview