# check how much items are scrolled during recyclerview scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, vertical-scrolling

I have recyclerview with LinearLayout Manager, during scrolling i want to check that how much items scrolled. For example, if recyclerview have 10 items, and i want to trigger an event after 6 items scrolled then what is the logic. Please give your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Read the aswer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview

Comment: Hoàng Vũ Anh, I cannot figure out the solution with is reference link.