# Android - Is there any approach to detect and count users who viewed the item in recyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, analytics, metrics

Metric All post.
I have a social media app project, and I want to detect and count the number of user who view the specific post/item in a recyclerView. Hope you have any idea about this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

put count in your model class

```
int readCount
```

Like

```
class MyAdapterModelClass {
......
int readCount
......

void incrementReadCount(){
readCount++;
}
}

onBindViewHolder(position, holder){
items.get(position).incrementReadCount();
}
```

Comment: this won't actually work correctly, because the recyclerview will bind a few items ahead of what is seen on the screen

Comment: you can use first and last visible item using layout manager 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview
Let me know if its works

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'll let you know once I try it. Thank you!