# How to get the total of elements that my recycler view can show on screen when it loaded?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a Recycler View that is showing a list of elements.
My list has 100 elements and after building the list and load in recycler I need to know how many elements I can see on my screen.

Follow the image below :

[image]

I need to know the number of elements that I can see in the list. In that example, following the number of Add Buttons as a reference, They are 4 elements.

Comment: Follow this - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the on-screen item count as follow

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

//get on-screen items count.
int currentItems = layoutManager.getChildCount();

//get total items count.
int totalItems = layoutManager.getItemCount();

//get scroll-out items count
int scrollOutItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```