# Access data from RecyclerView Item when visible on screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to access the underlying data from a `recyclerview` item when it scrolls onto the screen.

I am using `onAttachedToRecyclerView()` inside my Adapter class. Then get the data within `onScrolled()`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    val manager = recyclerView.layoutManager
    Log.i("ProductAdapter","$manager")
    if (manager is StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
        val slm: StaggeredGridLayoutManager = manager
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                val firstVisibleItemPosition: Int
                val firstVisibleItemPositions =
                    slm.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(null)
                firstVisibleItemPosition = firstVisibleItemPositions[0]
                if (firstVisibleItemPosition > -1) {
                    val item = getItem(firstVisibleItemPosition))
                    // do stuff with item data
                }
            }
        })
    }else{
        Log.e("ProductAdapter","error")
    }
}
```

when I set `val manager = recyclerView.layoutManager`, `manager` ends up being null. So the first if check never passes.  My code is referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview/56417765#56417765) answer from another question.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you setting the ``LayoutManager`` on the ``RecyclerView`` **before** you set the ``Adapter``?

Comment: I was not. Just changed the code in my fragment. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Fragment I was setting the adapter for the recyclerview one line before setting the layout manager.

Code before:

```
recyclerViewProducts.apply {
            this.adapter = productAdapter
            layoutManager = staggeredGridLayoutManager
            itemAnimator?.changeDuration = 0
        }
```

Code after:

```
recyclerViewProducts.apply {
            layoutManager = staggeredGridLayoutManager
            this.adapter = productAdapter
            itemAnimator?.changeDuration = 0
        }
```

Thanks to cactustictacs