# time picker dialog customisation or like that type of dialog creation

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker

i am trying to build dialog as in pic as follows as

[image]

i have try two recycler view  and constraint layout to show time in specific highlighted  view but i have no idea when next button click how to get time that will be  in area of constraint highlighted area or is there any other way to do this help will be appreciated and my code as follow

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lltimer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvHours"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvMints"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />


    </LinearLayout>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constrainBg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_28sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_gray"
        android:alpha="0.3"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_12sdp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"

        />
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview. Depending on how that gray area is draw, the selected element will either be a fixed offset or a percentage offset from the first visible item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done it by using this lib that is use full for me
https://github.com/OzcanAlasalvar/DatePicker